# `npm pkg set` command does not reflect variable type properly

Tags: npm, npm-package

How to make a property remain its type when using `npm pkg set` command?
We are using latest npm currently. We just followed the docs,
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-pkg?v=true

Commands:

```bash
npm pkg set 'prettier.printWidth'=100
npm pkg set 'prettier.singleQuote'=true
```

Expected result:

```
// package.json
{
  // ...

  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 100
  }
}
```

Actual result:

```
// package.json
{
  // ...

  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": "true",
    "printWidth": "100"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `--json` flag, the value will be added after parsing as json. Therefore type would be remained.

> It's also possible to parse values as json prior to saving them to your package.json file, for example in order to set a "private": true property

```bash
npm pkg set 'prettier.printWidth'=100 --json
npm pkg set 'prettier.singleQuote'=true --json
```